# Is the BXNewFolder tool safe to use?

Tags: windows, software-rec, virus

Can the BXNewFolder utility cause any problems with my computer, like a virus or something as damaging?

I'm just wondering if it's safe to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 2 kind of information i found in the internet.

```
****bxNewFolder is used to run use with  bxNewFolder.dll***
```

***[Its is safe](http://www.fileinspect.com/fileinfo/bxnewfolder-dll/)***

bxNewFolder.dll  file is part of bxNewFolder. It’s a hidden file. Bxnewfolder.dll is usually located in the PROGRAM_FILES/sub-folder and its usual size is 191,488 bytes.

The bxnewfolder.dll process is safe, and you can safely disable it.

[***Its not is safe***](http://www.file.net/process/bxnewfolder.dll.html)

bxNewFolder.dll is located in a subfolder of "C:\Program Files" or sometimes in a subfolder of C:. The file size on Windows XP is 191,488 bytes.
This .dll file is a Browser Helper Object (BHO) that runs automatically every time you start your Internet browser. BHOs are not stopped by personal firewalls, because they are identified by the firewall as your browser itself. BHOs are often used by adware and spyware. The unique ID of this BHO is 51C8BCA8-2524-4523-BF09-738C4EEBFC58. The application has no file description. The program has no visible window. File bxNewFolder.dll is able to monitor Internet browser. The service has no detailed description. It is not a Windows core file. bxNewFolder.dll seems to be a compressed file. Therefore the

Important: Some malware camouflage themselves as bxNewFolder.dll, particularly if they are located in c:\windows or c:\windows\system32 folder. Thus check the bxNewFolder.dll process on your pc whether it is pest.
Conclusion :

## Technical security rating is 82% dangerous